# How to add newline to textarea after label

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the following pattern which is from Microsoft Word:

[image]

and in HTML I'm getting:

[image]

How do i code it in the way where the textarea is after the label like the visualization in word above?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Enter your address</label>
        <textarea id = "addr_out"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide your css code if you wrote for this

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the `entity` a flexbox container and use
   `margin-bottom` for the entity label.
2. Use `rows` attribute to enlarge the text area
   according to your desired layout.

```css
.entity {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Vertical alignment of the flexbox container */
  width: 300px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Go down you Textarea! */
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #70AD47;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Enter your address</label>
    <textarea id="addr_out" rows="10"></textarea> <!-- Change rows to increase height -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a couple of ways:

(old hack) would be adding `<br>` after the label but I don't recommend this:

```
<label >Enter your address</label><br/>
```

Or you can also make it so the label and the textarea is wrapped on a different `div` considering that div is full width:

```
<div class = "entity">
   <label >Enter your address</label>
</div>
<div class = "entity">
   <textarea id = "addr_out"></textarea>
</div>
```

OR you can do it on css, either make the label width `100%`:

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

OR make the `.entity` use `flex`:

```
.entity {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add [`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```css
#addr_out {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="entity">
    <label>Enter your address</label>
    <textarea id="addr_out"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply, add `<br/>` tag between `<label>` and `<textarea>` selectors.
2. You can change the style of `<label>` with `display: block`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Enter your address</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea id = "addr_out"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**What about something like this**

I added some css code to make your `label` & `textarea` according to your need.

```css
.entity label::after{
      content: "\a";
      white-space: pre;
}
.entity textarea{
      border: 2px solid green;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Enter your address</label>
        <textarea id = "addr_out"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Explaination:**

**Css Line 2:-**  Set the `content` property to `"\a"` (this character for new-line) after `label` using `::after` pseudo-class.

**Css Line 3:-**  Set `white-space` property to `pre`. because the browser will read every white-space, in your given class, as a white-space.

**Css Line 6:-**   Set the border of `textarea` thick and green.

**Css Line 7 & 8:-**   Set the height and width to `200px` and `100px` respectively, to make it enlarge.

**Css Line 9:-**   Set top margin to `5px`, to add more space.

**Css Line 10:-**  Set the `resize` property to `none` to tell the browser to do not make the `textarea` resizable.

Hope this will helpful for you, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `display: block` for all labels inside a specific div, in this case ".entity" for example or a parent div used to contain your form. With this approach all the labels you add inside this div will follow the same layout automatically. See example below.

I don't recommend using `<br>` after a label as some of the other answers suggest here. The reason is because any additional label you add will require you to manually do the same. Not only this approach relies on human action but it will also flood your code with unnecessary html tags.

```css
.entity label {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>testform</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "entity">
        <label >Enter your address</label>
        <textarea id = "addr_out"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```